# Unable to find SBT in Jenkins while the plugin is installed

Tags: sbt, jenkins-pipeline

I've installed the sbt plugin for Jenkins under the **global tool configuration**. 
But Jenkins tells me it can't find the sbt command when I run my build

the Jenkinsfile

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build Image') {
            steps {
                echo "Build Image"
                sh 'sbt buildDockerImage'
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Error message;

```
 [Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build Image)
[Pipeline] echo
Build Image
[Pipeline] sh
+ sbt buildDockerImage
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/App-ImageBuild@tmp/durable-1de2b2d2/script.sh: line 1: sbt: command not found
09:01:18.926552 durable_task_monitor.go:63: exit status 127
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first delete `#!/usr/bin/env groovy` since you are using declarative pipeline, not a scripted one.

Second, the issue is that the tool is being installed by Jnekins in it's home directory which is not included in the **PATH** environment variable. As such,
you should specify the full path to **sbt** executable:

```
steps {
    echo "Build Image"
    sh "${tool name: 'mySbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt  buildDockerImage"
}
```

replace **'mySbt'** with the name you specified at Global Tools Configuration page.

As an alternative solution, you can just add sbt dir to PATH env var by adding following block:

```
environment {
     SBT_HOME="${tool 'mySbt'}"
     PATH="${env.SBT_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
}
```

replace **'mySbt'** with the name you specified at Global Tools Configuration page.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix
First, find the absolute path for sbt in your machine

```
 which sbt
```

> /usr/local/bin/sbt

Then, add the full path to groovy script:

```
sh '/usr/local/bin/sbt buildDockerImage'
```